# Stop AV Player after done is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get my local video to load into a new view controller, but after hitting done it disappears and immediately pops back up again. I don't know if there is a way to track the notifications or what.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoController1: UIViewController {

    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jamesjarrett/Desktop/NIMS/NIMS/NIMS/Vid2.mp4")
        playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
        playerViewController.player = playerView
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true){
            self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: keep a bool to make it show only once. viewDidAppear is called everytime the view is shown and therefore the av player pops up back

Answer (score 0):

You put your code

```
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jamesjarrett/Desktop/NIMS/NIMS/NIMS/Vid2.mp4")
    playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
    playerViewController.player = playerView
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true){
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
```

inside of ViewDidAppear for the ViewController.

ViewDidAppear() occurs when your view is presented on the screen again. So this means, that when the AVPlayer is closed, it goes back to that View, and the AVPlayer will be presented again.

You have 2 options:

Make a UIButton and an Action to that button

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(0, self.view.frame.height*0.9, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height*0.1))
button.addTarget(self, #selector(VideoController1.playController), nil)
self.view.addSubview(button)    

let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jamesjarrett/Desktop/NIMS/NIMS/NIMS/Vid2.mp4")

func playController() {
    playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
    playerViewController.player = playerView
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true){
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

-- OR --

If you want the controller to play only the first time the user sees the view, and that is it, then you can do

```
var played = false

func viewDidAppear() {
    if(!played) {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jamesjarrett/Desktop/NIMS/NIMS/NIMS/Vid2.mp4")
        playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
        playerViewController.player = playerView
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true){
            played = true
            self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Don't quote me on the code above, just typed it up real quick to give you a general idea.

Comment: So I was trying to add a button to the interface and use the first method you mentioned but it does look that way in swift

Comment: Button.addTarget(self, #selector(className.playController), .TouchUpInside)

Comment: Tried to upvote but because I'm new to overflow it says I have to have x number of rep points. Thanks for your help @impression7vx

Comment: You should be able to Accept the answer, if you'd like! No problem!